# Can't deploy my App Engine since SDK 1.9.46

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, google-app-engine-deploy

Since I upgraded my Gradle build to deploy my App Engine application with SDK 1.9.46, I get deployment conflict messages, like the one below.

```
Beginning interaction for module admin...
0% Created staging directory at: '/var/folders/m8/6z4h4k2x11s3whxrqmd79lym0000gn/T/appcfg2292422843793738444.tmp'
5% Scanning for jsp files.
8% Generated git repository information file.
20% Scanning files on local disk.
25% Scanned 250 files.
28% Scanned 500 files.
31% Scanned 750 files.
33% Scanned 1000 files.
34% Initiating update.
Nov 13, 2016 11:11:41 AM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?module=admin&app_id=the-outdoor-game&version=dev&
409 Conflict
There is an operation pending for this application: AppLock held for "Updating engine_version_id='dev' within engine_id='default'." acquired by Peter.Fortuin at 2016-11-13 09:15:05.482616 GMT.  Please wait and try again or use 'appcfg rollback' to attempt to cleanly abort the current operation.
This is try #0
```

A rollback if not solving the problem. The only thing that seems to work is downgrading the App Engine SDK to 1.9.44. But that gives me other problems that I don't want to solve.

Anybody has any idea how to solve this? Can it be that this is a bug in the 1.9.46 SDK? Anybody else seeing the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem by changing 'service' to 'module' in appengine-web.xml of my module.
See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin/issues/268 for more information.